# Is there a plugin or tool which I can use to generate coverage from running application without testcases?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage, maven-plugin, wildfly-swarm

I have a Java based web application which have few ReST endpoints exposed. I want to check the code coverage in running VM. Is there any tool or plugin I can use for this purpose?

I tried looking into **jacoco** but It looks like it provides code coverage only if you have configured unit/integration tests.

Sometimes, it becomes very difficult to write testcases for all possible scenarios. So, is there a way I can get code coverage without test cases?

Thanks a ton in advance. :)

Comment: generate coverage without test cases, not possible

Comment: I do not understand your question. A code coverage tools measures what part of your code is executed when you run a test. You say you do not want to write tests. So if there is no test there is no coverage to be recorded. Do you want to see what part of your application is used by users in production?

Comment: @cmoetzing :Yes, I want to see what part of my code is executed(line by line), when the service is used by an user. If I can get a plugin/tool which can solve this problem, I can run service at local to see the code lines executed in running application.

Comment: @G.G. And then what do you want to do with that data? There are tools that gather data during runtime like [inspectIT](http://www.inspectit.rocks/) but they do not provide the same data JaCoCo does. inspectIT can record a call hierarchy so you can explore which code was executed by a specific WS call for example. It does not aggregate data over several calls (not that I know of at least).

Comment: @cmoetzing I want to know which part of my service code was not touched during runtime. There are various conditional checks in the code at various places which results in different code flow to be executed depending on its usage. So, need to know which piece of code is executed and which is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more search on internet, I have found a very good link which fulfill my requirements:
https://automationrhapsody.com/code-coverage-of-manual-or-automated-tests-with-jacoco/

In short, follow below steps to generate code coverage report without testcases:

1. Install Jacoco Eclipse plugin: EclEmma Java Code Coverage
2. Download jacocoagent.jar and put it some location on your computer e.g. 
   C:\JoCoCo\jacocoagent.jar
3. Run your application with this VM arguments: **- 
   javaagent:C:\JaCoCo\jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver**
4. Import coverage reports:File -> Import -> Coverage Session -> select Agent 
   address radio button but leave defaults -> enter some name and select code 
   under test.